# TrustProxies and Laravel returning the IP address of my server, not the end user

Tags: php, laravel, proxy, laravel-5.6

I am looking at documentation here: [fideloper/TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) and [Laravel 5.6 Trusted Proxies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies).

I am set up with Laravel, with Forge managing servers.

This is the middleware defined in `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EnvMiddleware::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \ChaseConey\LaravelDatadogHelper\Middleware\LaravelDatadogMiddleware::class
];
```

This is `TrustProxies.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies = '**';

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

In API calls, `$request->ip()` returns the correct IP address in staging - which is not load balanced.

However, this returns the value of one of my two load balanced servers in production.

These are the installed `composer.json` packages:

`"laravel/framework": "5.6.*"`

`"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0"`

I have tried both:

`protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;`

and

`protected $headers = Request:: HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe your setup? I'm guessing you have an AWS ELB connected to two EC2s?

Comment: It is not an ELB as defined in AWS. I am using Laravel Forge's functionality to load balance (it creates an EC2 server).

Comment: Hmm I see. I'm not familiar with forge but it's best to check what headers it forwards and set the `$headers` appropriately. Pretty sure that's your error.

Comment: It seems that with Laravel 5.6, the other headers no longer exist on the `Request` class.

Comment: Hi @rail24, did you solved this?